# How to find out if a tag has a specific class AND id

Tags: jquery, html, css

Have a body tag on a page that has both an id and a class:

```
<body class="class" id="id">
```

I'm trying to use jQuery to chance some content further down the page, based on what the class AND the id are. I've had no success, for what it's worth, here's what I tried to do:

```
if($('body').is('#id1')){
    if($(this).hasClass('class1')){
        $('ul.nav li.first').html('<h2>Special Title</h2>');
    }else if($(this).hasClass('class2')){
        $('ul.nav li.first').html('<h2>Other Title</h2>');
    }
}else if($('body').is('#id2')){
    if($(this).hasClass('class1')){
        $('ul.nav li.first').html('<h2>Special Header</h2>');
    }else if($(this).hasClass('class2')){
        $('ul.nav li.first').html('<h2>Other Title</h2>');
    }
}
```

Anyone have a quick way of doing this? I'm terrible at "if" looping using jQuery, always have been.

Cheers,

T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the record there is no need to use jQuery here.

```
var isId = (document.body.id === someId);
var isClass = (document.body.className.indexOf(someClass) !== -1);

if (isId && isClass) {
     // do something
}
```

[Edit]

The class check is horrible. Try

```
var regexp = new RegExp("(^|//s)" + someClass + "($|//s)", "m");
var isClass = (document.body.className.search(regexp) !== -1);
```

Comment: when is there a !need! to use jQuery at all?

Comment: Until you have `class12` in the `className`. I agree on the `id` thing, but jQuery makes class manipulation approximately 13.63 times easier.

Comment: That's not a great class check: it will return `true` when checking for class "foo" on an element with class "foobar", for example. I'd recommend something like `new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + someClass + "(\\s|$)").test(document.body.className);` instead.

Comment: @Tim Down: probably `$.inArray('someClass', document.body.className.split(/\s/) > -1)` using jQuery.

Comment: @TimDown @jAndy I actaully added a proper class check. Thanks for ruining the simplicity. Your only giving a good reason to use jQuery because vanilla JS is a bit clunky.

Comment: @TimDown: well true, probably a bad spot :p

Comment: @Raynos: It is how it is. Developers will always be drawn to the simple API and safety-in-numbers confidence that things like jQuery offer rather than a scary-looking piece of code posted by a guy on a website.

Comment: @TimDown jQuery is great for heavy DOM manipulation, event handling or ajax. It's frustrating to see it get used for trivial little things though. Admittedly the fact that `className` is a space deliminated list of classes doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. For anyone wondering, I never defined what `$(this)` is. Replaced it with `$('body')` and it works now.

Sorry all. Move along, nothing to see here!